# Is it a bad architecture to build part of the app with Laravel and users authentication and chat in firebase

Tags: php, laravel, firebase

I have e-learning system of 1 course contain customized course content and related modules plus a complete module of user messaging (including audio messages and real-time chat). It is a Mobile app also so I will build REST API in Laravel.

My question: is it a bad practice or have potential drawbacks if I developed the whole users,authentication,real-time chatting and messaging modules in Firebase and the rest of the app related to content itself in Laravel and the link will be with user id.

I don't prefer Firebase in the content management part. It is inflexible for the relational nature of the content.

Comment: do you want to make API's in laravel.

Comment: I don't get your comment and how is it related to the question. But in general I will make APIs yes for mobile app.

Comment: in question you asking structure is right or wrong ?

Comment: Is there way to use Laravel in mobile app code ?

Comment: i would stay away from it. You can do everything you want inside Laravel, when you split it up you will have a lot of unnecessary hassle

Comment: But Laravel will take more time to handle 1- authentication with social media, 2-real-time chat and messaging. Plus the performance is better if we used Firebase for this.